# Ad on the bottom of PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, admob, preferenceactivity

I've implemented Admob in my PreferenceActivity as a custom preference. It works, even though the ad gets a little cut of, but when I scroll down and up the ad disappears for a second and shows again.
Is it possible to place the add to the bottom of the screen, overlaying the preference list? (Like in a regular activity).

Comment: I would question the business value in displaying an ad at the bottom of a PreferenceActivity. Do you really expect your users to be spending significant amounts of time in a PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout for the Ad, Also set parameters for the Layout according to the coordinates of the screen, now add this layout to your main layout.

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(adWidth,adHeight);
    params.leftMargin=0;
    params.topMargin = h-adHeight;

    //adding Adview and other portion view to relative layout created
    myLayout.addView(adview,params); 
    myLayout.addView(yourotherportionview);

    setContentView(myLayout);
```